# iOS Chrome does not open .mobileconfig files in settings app like Safari does

Tags: javascript, ios

I am sharing Apple Configuration Profile (a `.mobileconfig` file) with people in our organisation via downloadable link. For those who have Safari as their default web browser, clicking the link opens the Settings app to install the profile. However, for many of the users who have Chrome as their default browser, the file is just downloaded. There is an option for "Open in..." but clicking on it shows that "No application on this device can open this file". One way is to tell the users to open the link in Safari. Is there any other way I can automatically open the installation from Chrome? I can put the link on a webpage and build some javascript logic around it but not sure what exactly I need to do to open the link in settings app.

Answer (score 3):

No you can't. Apple's website states that you can only open a .mobileconfig file with Safari, the Email app, OTA, or using Apple Configurator app.

Answer (score 0):

The user can set Safari as their default web viewer and then in the mobileiron/settings menu select re-enroll.  This will re-download the profile which can then be activated in 'Settings'.

I assume that other device management apps will have a similar function, if you are not on mobileiron.

After that, they can select Firefox as their default web viewer.

This seems to be the least painful way to get it done.